# jQuery Variable Function Won't Run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I attempting to make boxes in HTML where, if you hover over them, the icon in the box spins while fading out and in it's place another img fades in, but does not spin in. Well, I got it to work but there was so much code I tried to make a function so I'd have less code. I have been unable to find the answer to this, here is the code. What I wan't

http://jsfiddle.net/SSZVN/

Here is the code if you only need this to tell me:

```html
<div id="info-boxes">
  <div class="box b-one">
    <span class="rotate">
      <center><img src="images/house.png" alt="" title="Stability" class="rotata" /></center>
      <center><img src="images/house-h.png" alt="" title="Stability" class="rotati" /></center>
    </span>
    <h2>Stable & Secure</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetura
      dipiscing elit. Donec porta diam
      massa. Fusce molestie nisl in posuere 
      fermentum.</p>
    <center><a href="#" class="button-blue">More Info</a></center>
  </div>
  <div class="box b-two">
    <span class="rotate">
      <center><img src="images/note.png" alt="" title="Realiablity" class="rotata" /></center>
      <center><img src="images/note-h.png" alt="" title="Realiablity" class="rotati" /></center>
    </span>
    <h2>Reliable Information</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetura
      dipiscing elit. Donec porta diam
      massa. Fusce molestie nisl in posuere 
      fermentum.</p>
    <center><a href="#" class="button-green">More Info</a></center>
  </div>
  <div class="box b-thr">
    <span class="rotate">
      <center><img src="images/power.png" alt="" title="Savability" class="rotata" /></center>
      <center><img src="images/power-h.png" alt="" title="Savability" class="rotati" /></center>
    </span>
    <h2>Power Saver</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetura
      dipiscing elit. Donec porta diam
      massa. Fusce molestie nisl in posuere 
      fermentum.</p>
    <center><a href="#" class="button-red">More Info</a></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
var spinMe = function(nameSpin) {
    $(nameSpin).hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children('.rotata').fadeOut('slow');
        }, function() {
            $(this).children('.rotata').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    );
    $(nameSpin).hover(
        function() {
            $(this).hasClass('.rotati').fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
            $(this).hasClass('.rotati').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    );
};
spinMe('#info-boxes .box');
```

Comment: Don't link to live pages.

Comment: Sorry. Would screen shots be approved?

Comment: use a jsfiddle.net page instead, so that the code you're showing stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with changing the reference of the obj.

```
    $(this).find('img.rotata').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');

    and

    $(this).find('img.rotati').fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow');
```

though, I had to remove some of your JS code from your fiddle (didn't save of course), as I was getting JS errors that was preventing your spinning code from working. Once I removed that issue, the references were incorrect to the elements you wanted to spin. So I changed it to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).children('.rotata').each(function () {
  $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```